# R: Finding the difference between two points from the plot

Tags: r

I need to calculate the time difference of the each sample (the samples can be differentiate using ID column) between two temperature points.

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Zeit = c(0L, 180L, 360L, 420L, 600L, 604L, 0L, 180L, 
360L, 480L, 600L, 605L), Temp = c(963L, 824L, 666L, 658L, 641L, 
549L, 957L, 823L, 661L, 660L, 642L, 562L)), .Names = c("id", 
"Zeit", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is ggplot code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Zeit,y=Temp,group=id, colour=factor(id))) + geom_line(size=2)
```

Here is an image with extra explanation:

[image]

I need to calculate the time (Zeit) that i need to reach the temp = 600°C (Temp) for each of the sample (ID). So in this example for the ID sample 1, to reach 600°C (Temp column) i need 600 seconds.
I apprecieate any help!

Comment: You should make the question clearer.  Put the red text from your picture in the body text.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: expected output in this case is for example table with column **ID** (1 & 2) and second column with corresponding **Value** [600,602]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `approx` function.  For a target temperature Tt, the time required is given by:

```
with(data, approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = Tt))$y
```

If the temperature rises with time at any point, then this may be more complicated - you will need to specify the `ties` argument to `approx` (probably put `ties = min` in your context) - but it will work for your example as it is.  Note that the values I use for `x` and `y` are inverted with respect to your axes.

To get the table that you desire:

```
Zt <- vapply(unique(data$id), function(ID){
    with(data[data$id == ID,], approx(x = Temp, y = Zeit, xout = Tt))$y
}, double(1))
data.frame(id = unique(data$id), time = Zt)
```

Comment: is there any way i can get the value for each **ID** sample? so in this example for two samples with IDs =1 & 2?

Comment: Oh yeah.  Use: `with(data[data$id == ID,] , ...`  where `ID` is the ID value you wish to analyse.

Comment: i would like to get values for each id, like table with **ID** column and second column with **Values**

Comment: The edit should sort it out.  But really, the interesting bit of the question was finding out the time.  The rest is just handling R objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! exactly finding out the time was a bit tricky and interesting!